# On hover image rotate 45 degrees

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an image 45 degree (well actually I really want to make it wiggle back and forth) when I hover over.  I tried using CSS with the transform rotate with no luck.  Does anyone have any ideas (jQuery, javascript maybe)?

```
  a:hover{
            behavior:url(-ms-transform.htc);
            /* Firefox */
            -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
            /* Safari and Chrome */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
            /* Opera */
            -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
            /* IE9 */
            -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
            /* IE6,IE7 */}

 <div id="main">
    <span class="box"><a href=""><img src="blog-icon.png"></img></a></span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be setting the hover to the **anchor** instead of **image**..

Instead of

```
a:hover{
```

should be

```
img:hover{
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/9kAdP/)**

Comment: that worked great thanks.  If you wanna check out the page it's at:
http://johnverber.com

Comment: @Verber .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

In webkit browsers,`transform` is ignored on inline elements.

To make this work you would need to add `a { display:block; }` to your css. (Inline-block will also work)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Df6W/

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$("a img").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        mouseover : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:45})
        },
        mouseout : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
        }
     } 

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this several times and it works well:

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

```
$(".box a img").rotate(45);
```